# Is there a topos-theoretic notion of "dimension"?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, topos-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

It seems like almost any "topological" phenomenon has a generalization to toposes. For instance, in *Site Characterizations for Geometeric Properties of Toposes*, Olivia Caramello shows how we can compute topos theoretic analogues of discrete spaces, locally connected spaces, etc.

The notion of [Lebesgue Covering Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) seems like something which might be amenable to generalization to topoi, since there is already a lot of machinery around understanding (generalizations of) open covers and their refinements. However I can't find any references to *any* kind of topos theoretic "dimension", either on the nlab, googling or searching the arxiv for things like "topos dimension", or in any of the standard references (Borceux Vol 3, Maclane and Moerdijk, Goldblatt's book, Johnstone's "Topos Theory", as well as The Elephant™).

Of course, following Colin McLarty in the talk *Nevertheless One Should Learn the Language of Topos* (available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmcbm5FxRJE)), we expect a topos to behave like a geometric object. If $X$ is a space, then we can identify $X$ with the terminal object of $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$, so we can think of a topos as being sheaves on some idealized geometric object represented by the terminal object.

Obviously when studying a geometric object, its "dimension" is frequently an invariant of much interest, so it surprises me that it's *this* hard to find anybody talking about a topos theoretic analogue. The question then:

> Is there a well studied notion of topos dimension? Or if not, have there been some beginning steps in this direction? Where can I read about it? Has it been used for anything?
>
> If there *isn't* a pre-existing notion of dimension, is there a reason why? Maybe some of the obvious ideas (like lebesgue covering dimension) don't actually work, or aren't particularly useful? I would still be interested in this case, particularly if there are some examples of things that have been tried and are known to have failed.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: Before you define some quantity you should have some idea of what it computes to in some concrete examples. So what do you expect the dimension of, say, the topos of $G$-sets for a discrete group $G$ to be? Particularly, what about $G = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ZhenLin -- I was actually curious about what the dimension of a topos of $G$-sets should be, but I don't have any intuition for it. Still, if we work with lebesgue covering dimension, we _do_ know what we should get for sheaf topoi, and that's already a large number of concrete examples. For instance the dimension of $\mathsf{Set}$ should surely be $0$, the dimension of $\mathsf{Sh}(S^1)$ should be $1$, etc.

Comment: If you forced me to guess, since $G$-sets are a topos on the site whose objects are subgroups of $G$ with the atomic topology, we would expect the dimension to behave like the dimension of a discrete topological space. So... if $G$ is finite (for simplicity), I guess we would expect the dimension to be $0$? But again, I don't have much intuition for this case.

Comment: Johnstone mentions this matter together with some references toward the end of the paper "The point of pointless topology". Also of note is https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.8418 after the general rule that invariants of thermodynamic formalism/ergodic theory are dimension-like.

Answer (score 4):

Section 7.2 of Lurie's Higher Topos Theory
explores various notions of dimension for toposes,
including the homotopy dimension and the cohomology dimension.

The former is a generalization of the Lebesgue covering dimension
in a sense that for any paracompact space its covering
dimension coincides with the homotopy dimension of its ∞-topos of sheaves.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Lurie's text is famously long, and I'll be the first to admit I don't know much about $\infty$-toposes. Do you know if this definition specializes to one that works for "classical" toposes? Iirc, $\infty$-toposes are those $\infty$-categories which "look like" the $\infty$ category of spaces, so it makes sense to ask for every $n$-connected object to have a global section... But I'm not even sure what an $n$-connected object would _be_ in the classical case.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: You can certainly define an analogue for ordinary toposes.  This shouldn't be too surprising, since the bicategory of toposes is equivalent to a certain bicategory of localic groupoids, e.g., topological groupoids and similar objects.  But I don't know any sources that discuss the classical case.